# Magento Check-out page - fine without SSL but HTTPS returns 403 You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server

Tags: apache, magento, ssl, https

One of my magento stores (ready to go to production) has been all fine untill today I added SSL to the apache server. the SSL installation is fine with the padlock showing in the address bar.

the problem is after clicking \\"check out\\” the server goes to https and returns (I have rewrite on)

https://www.thedomain.com/checkout/onepage/

---

Forbidden

You don\\’t have permission to access /index.php on this server.

### Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at www..... Port 443

the one page checkout works fine without SSL connection

my ssl configuration file (which stores the SSL key/certification locations) are as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory \\\"/usr/lib/cgi-bin\\\">
AllowOverride All
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

# SSL Engine Switch:
# Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

....
....

<FilesMatch \\\"\\\\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$\\\">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch \\\"MSIE [2-6]\\\” \\\\
nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \\\\
downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
# MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
BrowserMatch \\\"MSIE [17-9]\\\” ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

---

Nothing added into the apache error log.

As it works well without SSL the issue must be caused by the SSL coonfiguration, I have compared the SSL vhost setting to the non-SSL vhost still no luck

Anyone offer some help? this is the last step before this store goes live…

Comment: This might belong on serverfault or webmasters. imho, it's an Apache config issue. I'd answer, but I hacked my way thru setup each time.

Answer (score 1):

error_log after rising verbosity shows:

> Non-default virtual host with SSLVerify set to 'require' and
>   VirtualHost-specific CA certificate list is only available to clients
>   with TLS server name indication (SNI) support

Commenting out **SSLVerify require** in httpd.conf has fixed the problem.

Comment: Are you the OP? If so, we can flag the question to see about getting it moved to your new user...?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the secure base url from backend with the exact url for eg https://www.yourdomain.com